# How to call SharePoint URL from Console Application

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, console-application

Hi how can I call this API

http://YOUR_SERVER_URL/PATH_TO_SITE_CONTAINING_LIST/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?Cmd=ExportList&List={YOUR_LIST_GUID}

from Console Application

I used below Code

```
string ListExportURL = http://YOUR_SERVER_URL/PATH_TO_SITE_CONTAINING_LIST/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?Cmd=ExportList&List={YOUR_LIST_GUID};
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ListExportURL);
System.Net.NetworkCredential credentialCache = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password);
webRequest.Credentials = credentialCache;
webRequest.Method = "GET";
webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml";
HttpWebResponse res = webRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
Stream strem = res.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(strem);
string xmlResult= reader.ReadToEnd();
```

I am getting an error 403 forbidden. anyone please help

Answer (score 0):

You code is perfectly fine. just check below things,

1. If you put directly above url in browser, does it return xml data in browser, it should first work in browser

2/ Other thing which i suspect is that If above API is blocked from IIS, sometimes sharepoint admins blocks this due to security reason.

3. Also while passing credentials, make sure you are passing domain also, I have seen that it give unauthorized error is credentials is not password as below.

   ```
   System.Net.NetworkCredential credentialCache = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("onlyuserid", "password","domainname");
   ```

Comment: yes when I am hitting that url in browser that will download the xml file in response.